# What is the safest implementation for storing user credentials to retrieve at a later time?

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, app-store-connect

I'm about to begin building a web-app (most likely in PHP but that's not definite yet) that **requires** some statistics from a user's iTunes Connect account. As far as I can see, the only way to access this is using Apple's AutoIngestion tool which, in a nutshell, sends a HTTP request to their server.

The problem is that the HTTP request requires a plain text user password as a parameter. What would be the safest way to store a user's iTunes Connect credentials so that they can be later retrieved to send in the HTTP request?

Comment: Would it be feasible to have the user log in to iTunes through your app every time you need to access their data?

Comment: I'd like to avoid requiring the user to do that - I'd like to fetch this data periodically on my server without user interaction.